# Raycast Geometry Node Source Position

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am attempting to recreate some sort of line-of-sight sensor functionality using the Raycast node. Currently, my scene consists of two objects -- a terrain and a "sensor". The sensor is built from isolating some faces from a UV sphere that aim downward towards the terrain.

[image]

My current goal is to simply draw a cube or something on the terrain at each point where a ray cast from the center of the sensor through a normal of one of its faces would intersect the terrain surface. Here, is the geometry node setup:

[image]

Currently, the result is a single cube located at the origin.

[image]

The desired result is for the scenario shown would be a trail of cubes in the XZ-plane following the terrain. However, I would like to find a solution that works when the sensor is moved and, most importantly, rotated. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i am not sure, but i hope you want this?

[image]

[image]

if you animate changing the y value of the ray direction you will get:

[image]